# How to set permissions for users

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I am trying to set permissions for users my django project.
What I want to achieve is:

- User should be able to view/update only his information when logged in
- An non-logged in user should be able to create a new user

My code is as below.

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password')

        def create(self, validated_data):
            username = validated_data['username']
            email = validated_data['email']
            first_name = validated_data['first_name']
            last_name = validated_data['last_name']
            password = make_password(validated_data['password'])

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
            instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
            instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
            instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
            instance.password = make_password(validated_data.get('password', instance.password))
            instance.save()
            return instance
```

views.py

```
from urllib import request
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from atest.serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework import permissions
from atest.permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset provides operations on Users table to the same user.
    """

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

and permissions.py

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the snippet.
        return obj.username == request.user
```

I am able to successfully login. But when I opens individual users page i.e.

> http://localhost:8000/users/8/

I am not able to perform put,patch,delete methods

Comment: You should look into how Django manages user permissions. In general, there is a Permission object for each CRUD action on each model. A Group is basically a collection of Permissions that a user can be associated with and thereby have all permissions from the group associated with them. Check out the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) and [this article](https://djangobook.com/users-groups-permissions/) for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this permission class

```
# permissions.py
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class MyCustomPermissionClass(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        """
        You need to allow everyone to access the "list,create" apis. So, you should return "True" always
        """
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return request.user == obj  # here "obj" will be the "User" instance


# views.py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [MyCustomPermissionClass, ] 
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```